# VB Compile Time Error Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

I wrote a simple VB application that takes a string and puts it in a messagebox for the world to see:

```
Module Hello

Sub Main(ByVal saySomething As String)
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(saySomething) ' Display message on computer screen.
End Sub
```

I keep getting compile time errors.  Global.System.Web.HttpRequest is not defined.  First, I have no clue on getting that namespace into VB and, second, I don't need it because I am using VB.MsgBox and it worked fine when I had a literal in there.  I need to be able to pass parameters into VB code.  Please help! 
End Module

Comment: `dim saySomething = ""`
`Console.WriteLine("Say Something..."')`
`saySomething = Console.ReadLine()` have you tried something like this?

Comment: I don't know about the error message, but the main method should probably take a string array as the parameters like `Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)`, and adjust the other code to match `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(args(0))`.  You will probably want to verify that a parameter was passed in too (e.g. `If args.Length > 0 Then ...`).  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I tried Module Hello

    Sub Main()
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("Hello World") ' Display message on computer screen.
    End Sub


End Module    and it complied file using the command line compiler.  I am using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider compiler and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please what is your version of the Visual Studio? Also, could you try the same after you close your existing solution and create new project of type "Windows Forms Application"?

Comment: I am using VS2015.  I get the error in a fresh windows form app.  Full using stmnt 'using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform;
using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers;
using Microsoft.CodeDom;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;'

Comment: I don't think I am following along here. :-(  Are you saying that you are using code like shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider.aspx) to compile and that is getting the error?

Comment: I just commented out everything in my VB file and I get the same error.  I think it must have to do with how I am implementing the compiler.

Comment: Mark - yes and thanks for the link.  I'm going to try that version of the compiler and see if it works...

Comment: Yay -- that compiler worked and you solved the parameters problem as well.  You rock it!!!  Thank you so, so much!